# How to add Toolbar to a fragment in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

I have a fragment named as HomeFragment.java and it extends Fragment class.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.example.android.test.R;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile,container,false);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        getActivity().setSupportActionController(toolbar);
        //setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        return view;
    }
}
```

But I am getting error in the line:

```
getActivity().setSupportActionController(toolbar)
```

And the error is:

```
Cannot resolve method 'setSupportActionController(android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar)'
```

And **there is a condition** that I can't extend my **HomeFragment** to **AppCombatActivity**. It has to be remained as **Fragment** only, i.e. **public class HomeFragment extends Fragment**.

The condition is because of line number 5 in this piece of code

```
    Runnable mPendingRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // update the main content by replacing fragments
            Fragment fragment = getHomeFragment();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in,
                    android.R.anim.fade_out);
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, fragment, CURRENT_TAG);
            fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
        }
    };

    // If mPendingRunnable is not null, then add to the message queue
    if (mPendingRunnable != null) {
        mHandler.post(mPendingRunnable);
    }

    // show or hide the fab button
    toggleFab();

    //Closing drawer on item click
    drawer.closeDrawers();

    // refresh toolbar menu
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
}
```

And my getHomeFragment() is:

```
    private Fragment getHomeFragment() {
    switch (navItemIndex) {
        case 0:
            // home
            HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
            return homeFragment;
        case 1:
            // photos
            PhotosFragment photosFragment = new PhotosFragment();
            return photosFragment;
        case 2:
            // movies fragment
            MoviesFragment moviesFragment = new MoviesFragment();
            return moviesFragment;
        case 3:
            // notifications fragment
            NotificationsFragment notificationsFragment = new NotificationsFragment();
            return notificationsFragment;

        case 4:
            // settings fragment
            SettingsFragment settingsFragment = new SettingsFragment();
            return settingsFragment;
        default:
            return new HomeFragment();
    }
}
```

So if I change **public class HomeFragment extends Fragment** to **public class HomeFragment extends AppCombatActivity**, the return statement in the above code will give **incompatible type error**.

Please help me in resolving this error, I can't make toolbar or actionbar because of this error. 
Any help will be appreciable.
Thankyou!

Comment: Why would you do `HomeFragment extends AppCompatActivity` if it's not an Activity? You need to cast `getActivity`, presumably

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cast your activity from `getActivity()` to `AppCompatActivity` first. I think this will solve your error:

```
((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Or in your case:

```
((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionController(toolbar);
```

`getActivity()` returns a `FragmentActivity` and you need to get `AppCompatActivity` returned.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(editGroupTool); //toolbar id
((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle(" "); 
((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```